# how to set the default css validation scheme in visual studio 2010?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

well the problem is that visual studio always tries to validate for css 1.0 as i open any file and i need to reset it to 2.1 every time i open any css file.
so was asking if there is any way to set the default to be 2.1 ?
thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i found the answer on http://forums.asp.net/t/1486063.aspx/1
well its seems that to change the default css validation you need to change the default html validation from Tools>Options>Text Editor>HTML>Validation.
so i changed the target to XHTML 1.0 Transitional and now the css is validated to 2.1 by default :)